# Way to use JCL to pull in all GDG generations except for most recent (0)?

Tags: mainframe, jcl, dsn

Seeing if JCL has the capability to pull in all generations of a GDG except for the most recent generation?

Say I have on my mainframe:

```
A.GDG.FILE
A.GDG.FILE.G0001V00
A.GDG.FILE.G0002V00
A.GDG.FILE.G0003V00
```

I want to write JCL that will automatically only pull in generations 1 and 2. Likewise, if I have 4 generations, it would pull in 1, 2 and 3. Does this capability exist? Or would I need to copy my most recent generation to another file and remove it from this GDG and pull in all generations?

Comment: Can you give us some more insights into what you are trying to do as this might be an X-Y problem. Is there any reason why you can't run your job before the new generation is created?

Comment: Bit of a specific use case. Running into situations where a file is FTPd to our mainframe and often they will just send the file until it works. So writing a new job to clean it out and only keep the good one. The file is sent to a GDG rather than a flat file due to the processing job needing to be able to run multiple files when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can only retrieve all GDG dataset in JCL. In your example it would look like:

```
//SYSIN  DD DSN=A.GDG.FILE,DISP=SHR
```

Uou can also control the order by specifying LIFO, FIFO and USECATLG as in these examples:

```
//SYSIN  DD DSN=A.GDG.FILE,DISP=SHR,GDGORDER=LIFO
//SYSIN  DD DSN=A.GDG.FILE,DISP=SHR,GDGORDER=FIFO
//SYSIN  DD DSN=A.GDG.FILE,DISP=SHR,GDGORDER=USECATLG
```

- LIFO - last in first out
- FIFO - first in first out
- USECATLG - use catalogue order (defaults to LIFO)